# Enabling SSH Daemon from Terminal (OS X Lion)

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, osx-lion

I am trying to find a way of turning on SSH through terminal, instead of opening settings and turn it on that way. Or perhaps a way to turn SSH on by running a .pkg file?

I am running OS X Lion, but it would be great if it also worked on Snow Leopard!

Answer (score 11):

**enable remote login**

```
systemsetup -setremotelogin on
```

**disable remote login**

```
systemsetup -setremotelogin off
```

Comment: Can i allow it for a specific user via terminal?

Answer (score 5):

You may have to sudo:

```
    sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found terminal WILL ask:

*Do you really want to turn remote login off? If you do, you will lose this connection and can only turn it back on locally at the server (yes/no)?*

Typing 'yes' in scripts is not always possible.
To resolve this, use a **-f** flag before -setremotelogin, like so:

```
systemsetup -f -setremotelogin on
systemsetup -f -setremotelogin off
```

Comment: Actually, it's needed enough that most *nix systems come with `yes`.